# RadGrid Custom Filter

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I'm trying to add a custom filter to my RadGrid.  I have a column, vendNum, which I want to allow users to filter on multiple vendNums with a comma-separated list.  Basically, I want the same functionality as an "in" statement in SQL (where vendNum in (X,Y,Z)).

I followed the tutorial on [this site](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grdcustomoptionforfiltering.html) and came up with the following code to place in my RadGrid1_ItemCommand event.

```
 protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.FilterCommandName)
            {
                Pair filterPair = (Pair)e.CommandArgument;
    
                switch (filterPair.Second.ToString())
                {               
                    case "vendNum":
                        TextBox tbPattern = (e.Item as GridFilteringItem)["vendNum"].Controls[0] as TextBox;
                        if (tbPattern.Text.Contains(","))
                        {
                            string[] values = tbPattern.Text.Split(',');
                            if (values.Length >= 2)
                            {
                                e.Canceled = true;
                                StringBuilder newFilter = new StringBuilder();
                                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                                {
                                    if (i == values.Length - 1)
                                        newFilter.Append("[vendNum] = " + values[i]);
                                    else
                                        newFilter.Append("[vendNum] = " + values[i] + " OR ");
                                }
                                if (RadGrid1.MasterTableView.FilterExpression == "")
                                    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.FilterExpression = newFilter.ToString();
                                else
                                    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.FilterExpression = "((" + RadGrid1.MasterTableView.FilterExpression + ") AND (" + newFilter.ToString() + "))";
                                RadGrid1.Rebind();
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Doing this, though, keeps giving me an error "Expression Expected" when I try to filter with a comma separated list.  I'm still able to filter a single vendNum.  My `FilterExpression` does come out as expected.  The code is failing on the `RadGrid1.Rebind()` statement.  Has anyone dealt with this before?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Aaron

**Forgot to Edit This**

I solved this problem weeks ago...I had to set the "EnableLinqExpressions" property to false under the RadGrid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I saw this as a fix for this question somewhere.

Try adding:
RadGrid1.EnableLinqExpressions = false;

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I had to do.